# Custom Visual Studio solution

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I'm using these tools and technologies:

- Visual Studio 2019 CE
- Windows 10
- SQL Server
- C# and ASP.NET MVC

Currently I create a new Visual Studio 2019 solution.

1. Add three/four nuget packages (automatically targets MVC).
2. Change a couple of files.
3. Setup configuration files.
4. Add standard/default project images.

I now start to develop the site as required.

I will check-in the project into Azure DevOps at the end of the day.

Is there a way to do the above 4 steps by the means of a template/package that I set once so in future I can click a few buttons in Visual Studio and all 4 steps have been done for me rather than having to do each step manually?

**Errors**

**Error 1**

This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is ..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.2.0.1\build\net46\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props.

After attempting to Restore the packages

**Error 2**

An error occurred while trying to restore packages: Unable to find version 'XXXX' of package 'AAAA' C:\Program files(x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages: Package 'AAAA' is not found on source C:\Program files(x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages.... https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json Package 'AAAA' is not found on source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-project-templates?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is something called a [multi-project template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-multi-project-templates?view=vs-2019). That same page has a specific section on [creating a multi-project template from an existing solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-multi-project-templates?view=vs-2019#create-a-multi-project-template-from-an-existing-solution):

> 1. Create a solution and add two or more projects.
> 2. Customize the projects until they are ready to be exported to a template.
> 3. On the Project menu, choose Export Template.
> 4. The Export Template Wizard opens.
> 5. On the Choose Template Type page, select Project Template. Select one of the projects that you want to export to a template, and then
>    choose Next. (You'll repeat these steps for each project in the
>    solution.)
> 6. On the Select Template Options page, enter a name and optional description, icon, and preview image for your template. Choose Finish.
> 7. The project is exported into a .zip file and placed in the specified output location.
> 8. Create a directory for your template, with a subdirectory for each project.
> 9. Extract the contents of each project's .zip file into the corresponding subdirectory that you created.
> 10. In the base directory, create an XML file with a .vstemplate file extension. This file contains the metadata for the multi-project
>     template. See the example that follows for the structure of the file.
>     Be sure to specify the relative path to each project's vstemplate
>     file.
> 11. Select all the files in the base directory, and from the right-click or context menu, choose Send to > Compressed (zipped)
>     folder. The files and folders are compressed into a .zip file.
> 12. Copy the .zip file into the user project template directory. By default, this directory is %USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio
>     \Templates\ProjectTemplates.
> 13. In Visual Studio, choose File > New > Project and verify that your template appears.

Comment: Thanks - so far so good however when i create a new project from the template, its failing to restore any of the Nuget packages. Any idea? I will mark this as the answer soon

Comment: The nuget packages are always downloaded during the  build. Otherwise the template would become huge. Same reason we don't store them on version control.

Comment: So when attempting to restore the nuget packages i receive the errors now included within my original thread

Comment: It seems you have a custom package that is not on nuget. You must either upload on nuget your aaaa package, or connect to a custom feed.

Comment: I will have to dig around to see how to get around this. There are 3 references in packages.config that have this issue so i dont know if its one of the third party nuget packages that referencing another component which isnt being downloaded. The idea is to see if i can get the zip file of the package with the issue, add it to our local server, add the URL for VS to search on and see what happens.